# I want to display a toast if internet connection is not there, got no idea how to do that

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, nodemailer

Here I'm sending a mail when the form is submitted. Everything is working fine, the only issue is even though the internet connection is not present,the user is getting the success. I want that the user should get an error message if the internet connection is not there.

> script

```
this.mail= function() {
var data = ({
    name :this.name,
    email :this.email

})

//Post Request
$http.post('/send', data).
     success(function(response, status, headers, config){
          $mdToast.show(

                $mdToast.simple()
                  .textContent('Your form has been submitted '+data.name)
                  .position($scope.getToastPosition())
                  .hideDelay(5000)
              );
    }). 

    error(function(response, status, headers, config) {
        $mdToast.show(
         $mdToast.simple()
           .textContent('Something went wrong, Please TRY AGAIN '+data.name)
           .position($scope.getToastPosition())
           .hideDelay(5000)
       );

});
```

> server

```
function send(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);

  var data= req.body
  smtpTransport.sendMail({ 
     from: "<email@gmail.com>", 
     to: data.email, 
     subject: "Website Submission from "+data.name,
     text: 'You have a new submission with the following details...,
  }, function(error, response){  //callback
     if(error){
         console.log(error);
     }if(error.code == "ENOENT"){
         console.log("no internet connection");
     }else{
         console.log(" Message sent "+data.name);
     }

     smtpTransport.close(); 
  });
  res.json(data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http
The $http legacy promise methods success and error have been deprecated. Use the standard then method instead. If $httpProvider.useLegacyPromiseExtensions is set to false then these methods will throw $http/legacy error.

Don't use success/error.

Comment: i don't find much much difference between the two, I may be wrong but what I see here that the response object contains the data, status, headers and config properties which looks same to me from the legacy one. Anyways thanks for that, I changed my code to the new one :)

Comment: here the form is getting successfully posted, that's why I'm getting the toast. But the actual error is from the node mailer, this is what i want to display to the screen

Comment: Should this be a comment?

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript code

```
if(!window.navigator.onLine)
{
//you are not online
}
```

Comment: that's okay, but I want to get error from the response and  then display it 
on the screen something like this error.code == "ENOENT"